# get users geo location and echo out mysql results based on location?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to find our what city my users are in from their ip address to be able to display a list of users in my database close to them/in their area.

I have been looking at this api:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

and i have registered and got an api key, but im not sure where to go from here. Here is the example code they have used to get the users location:

```
<?php
include('ip2locationlite.class.php');

//Load the class
$ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
$ipLite->setKey('<api key>');

//Get errors and locations
$locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$errors = $ipLite->getError();

//Getting the result
echo "<p>\n";
echo "<strong>First result</strong><br />\n";
if (!empty($locations) && is_array($locations)) {
  foreach ($locations as $field => $val) {
    echo $field . ' : ' . $val . "<br />\n";
  }
}
echo "</p>\n";

//Show errors
echo "<p>\n";
echo "<strong>Dump of all errors</strong><br />\n";
if (!empty($errors) && is_array($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo var_dump($error) . "<br /><br />\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "No errors" . "<br />\n";
}
echo "</p>\n";

?>
```

but how would i now set a mysql query that says if the user location is london and users are listed as in london in the database then to display these to the user?

i would really appreciate a push in the right direction here if anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: You say "users are listed as in london in the database then to display these to the user?" What are 'these'? What is your database structure like? What information or data structure do you already have on the user?

Comment: basically in my mysql table i have user_location which stores the city of the user, i am now using a geo location api to get the user's city location by ip address and i want whatever the result is i.e. london or manchester then a mysql query will fetch all users with the user_location that = london/manchester.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (without knowing your database structure and untested ;). Insert this in the foreach ($locations as $field => $val) loop as below:

```
foreach ($locations as $field => $val) {
    echo $field . ' : ' . $val . "<br />\n";

    $mysqli = new mysqli('<mysql server>', '<mysql user>', '<mysql password>', '<database>');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error: Unable to connect to Database; ';
    } else {
        if ($stmt_evt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT <other_users>, ... FROM <your table> WHERE <user_location> LIKE ? ORDER BY <whatever>')) {
            $stmt_evt -> bind_param('s', $val);
            $stmt_evt -> execute();
            $stmt_evt -> bind_result($<other_users>, $...);
            while ($stmt_evt->fetch()) {
                echo 'Other users in your area: '.$<other_users>;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error: Unable to prepare Event statement.';
        }
    }
}
```